# VDSL to LTE redundancy over 2 different CPEs suitable for small business

Tags: redundancy, redundant-routes

We would like to build up a full redundant internet access to our small business location. We have currently VDSL connection and would like to create a redundant connection over LTE as a backup. In order to provide Hardware redundancy, I would like to deploy LTE over a separate CPE.

Currently I am looking for solution alternatives and do not own any router for the project yet. Based on the solution, I will select the routers for which I have a budget of 2000USD per router. Here I would like ask, from LAN network how we can detect VDSL problems and and change the default to route LTE modem?
BR,

Tolga

Comment: What network equipment do you have?

Comment: That completely depends on your router model. Please edit your question to include a good description (or better, a diagram) of your network, including the network device models and configurations (obfuscate any public addresses and passwords).

Comment: You don't need to determine it from the LAN. It still depends on the equipment, and you don't necessarily need two routers. For example, Cisco routers can use IP SLA and tracking to determine if a link is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can do is depend upon what equipment you use.
If your CPE routers support HSRP/VRRP configurations and VDSL router support IP SLA/Link monitoring/NQA...etc

- Configure HSRP/VRRP in lan interface of CPE router,
- Configure a IP SLA/Link monitoring/NQA on VDSL router to the next hop of VDSL link.
- Track the monitoring in HSRP/VRRP, configure priority as once the monitoring fails priority should decriment in VDSL router, so that router with LTE becomes HSRP/VRRP primary